# Update with OLAP on DB2/400 v7r2 and later

Tags: exception, olap, db2-400

Assume following scenario:

- 2x tables (tbl_1 and tbl_2) with identical data model as follows: userCol1, userCol2, internCol
- UserCol1 (Column A) is always empty (NULL) when row initially written into tables
- internCol (Column B) is filled by app with values determined by App

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2 |
|  | 4 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 5 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 2 |

Task: fill in a unique random value (here: hex(generate_unique()) where internCol shows multiple occurences, leave only 1st row as it is!

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2 |
|  | 4 |
| 12341231 | 2 |
|  | 5 |
| 22341232 | 2 |
| 32341233 | 2 |

1. First determine if multiple occurences are contained and if so then output

- occurance no.,
- values of columns
- from which table the rows are returned
  (this gives me a bunch of hits):

```
db2 "select 
  r.rn, tbl, userCol1, internCol
from (
  (
    select 
      row_number() over (partition by internCol order by internCol) as rn,
      'tbl_1' as tbl,
      userCol1, internCol 
    from tbl_1
    order by internCol
  ) 
  union
  (
    select 
      row_number() over (partition by internCol order by internCol) as rn,
      'tbl_1' as tbl,
      userCol1, internCol 
    from tbl_1
    order by internCol
  ) r
where r.rn>1 order by tbl,internCol"
```

2. If any multiple occurances found, update found rows in tbl_1 or tbl_2, set uniq random value in userCol1 (but leave the first occurence as it is) e.g.:

```
db2 "update 
  tbl_x u 
set userCol1=hex(generate_unique()) 
where (
  select row_number() over (partition by internCol order by internCol) as rn
  from tbl_1 
  order by internCol
)>1"
```

**Problem**: the where clause throws an exception
**** CLI ERROR *****
SQLSTATE: 21000
NATIVE ERROR CODE: -811
The result of a SELECT INTO, scalar fullselect, or subquery of a basic predicate is more than one value.

A) Anyone got an idea what's wrong here?
B) Of course it would be much nicer if update is able to determine by EXISTS() which table to update ;-)

Thanks to all contributors.

See details,

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2 |
|  | 4 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 5 |
|  | 2 |
|  | 2 |

should turn into

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 2 |
|  | 4 |
| 12341231 | 2 |
|  | 5 |
| 22341232 | 2 |
| 32341233 | 2 |

Comment: There is a mistake in 2nd block of UNION: of course the referenced table should be "tbl_2"! Thx

Comment: What you want is not clear. Do rows that have the same value in internCol but are in different tables count as duplicates or are you just trying to apply the same method to both tables in one query?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
To last question first: this is not a home work problem.

- the select with the UNION block over tbl1 and tbl2 shows if there are any duplicates even if 'across borders'. This works fine, see first result table with empty cells in Column A (usercol1) 
- the update is throwing the SQL exception.
P.s. after first SQL I had a look into tables one by one. In the sample above I found duplicates to be in the same table and tried to update

Thanks for your attention & further responses